# Laravel filtering users with categories associeted in BelongsToMany

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

in our application each category and user can associate with together.

each category can associate with one or many users and each user can associate with one or many categories

for example you suppose we have this category structure:

```
application
     web
         php
            laravel
            lumen
         web_design
            html
            css
            js 
     mobile    
         java
         flutter
```

in this structure each category can be have one or many child which we used `parent_id` in database structure to implementing them.

now, each one of this categories or some of categories associated with one or many user, for example:

```
application (Alfred)
     web (Alfred)
         php (Alfred)
            laravel (Alfred)
            lumen   (Alfred)
         web_design (Alfred)
            html (Alfred)
            css  (Alfred)
            js   (Alfred)
     mobile  (Alfred)   
         java (Alfred)
         flutter (Alfred)
```

all categories in this structure associated with this user:`(Alfred)` and each category can be associated with another user, for example:

```
application (Alfred)
     web (Alfred)
         php (Alfred,Ella)
            laravel (Alfred,Ella)
            lumen   (Alfred,Ella)
         web_design (Alfred,Elizabeth)
            html (Alfred,Elizabeth)
            css  (Alfred,Elizabeth)
            js   (Alfred,Elizabeth)
     mobile  (Alfred,Jack)   
         java (Alfred,Jack)
         flutter (Alfred,Jack)
```

or in the another word you can suppose we have this structure:

```
application (Alfred)
     web (Alfred)
         php (Alfred, Ella)
            laravel (Alfred, Ella)
            lumen   (Alfred,Ella ,Linda)
         web_design (Alfred, Elizabeth)
            html (Alfred,Elizabeth)
            css  (Alfred,Elizabeth)
            js   (Alfred,Elizabeth, Scarlett)
     mobile  (Alfred, Jack)   
         java (Alfred, Jack)
         flutter (Alfred, Jack, Jim)
```

this users are `BelongsToMany` with `Role`, which we synced them into database

1. Alfred    : **is-portal-manager**
2. Ella      : **is-manager**
3. Elizabeth : **is-manager**
4. Jack      : **is-editor**
5. Scarlett  : **is-writer**
6. Jim       : **is-writer**

we used `category_user` table to sync this structure to associating categories and users

then we have five table: `users`,`categories`, `roles` and middle tables: `category_user` and `role_user`

`migrations` database and tables:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->foreignId('user_id')->nullable()->constrained();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('family');
    $table->string('username');
    //...
});

Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('parent_id')->nullable();
    $table->string('name');
    //...
});

Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('label');
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('category_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreignId('category_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->primary(['category_id', 'user_id']);
});

Schema::create('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreignId('role_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->primary(['role_id', 'user_id']);
});
```

in the end, **whats our problem**:

we want to get logged user's categories which associated and defined with `category_user` table, that means when `Alfred` logging into system should be have all categories that associated with them.(one or many of categories), another users should be have the same strategy,

1. Alfred    : is-portal-manager (ALL CATEGORY WITH SUB CATEGORIES: application,web,php,laravel,lumen,web_design,html,css,js,mobile,java,flutter)
2. Ella      : is-manager (php,laravel,lumen)
3. Elizabeth : is-manager (web_design,html,css,js)
4. Jack      : is-editor  (mobile,java,flutter)
5. Scarlett  : is-writer  (js)
6. Jim       : is-writer  (flutter)

**COMPLETE STRUCTURE**:

```
application (Alfred: is-portal-manager)
     web (Alfred: is-portal-manager)
         php (Alfred: is-portal-manager, Ella: is-manager)
            laravel (Alfred: is-portal-manager, Ella: is-manager)
            lumen   (Alfred: is-portal-manager,Ella: is-manager ,Linda)
         web_design (Alfred: is-portal-manager, Elizabeth: is-manager)
            html (Alfred: is-portal-manager,Elizabeth: is-manager)
            css  (Alfred: is-portal-manager,Elizabeth: is-manager)
            js   (Alfred: is-portal-manager,Elizabeth: is-manager, Scarlett: is-writer)
     mobile  (Alfred: is-portal-manager, Jack: is-editor)   
         java (Alfred: is-portal-manager, Jack: is-editor)
         flutter (Alfred: is-portal-manager, Jack: is-editor, Jim: is-writer)
```

Models:

```php
class Category extends Model
{
    public function parent(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'parent_id', 'id', 'parent');
    }

    public function subcategories(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id', 'id');
    }

    public function users(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }
}

class Role extends Model
{
    public function users(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }
}

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * Get the parent User to which the current User belongs.
     */
    public function parent(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    /**
     * Get all Users which belong to the current User.
     */
    public function kids(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class);
    }

    public function categories(): BelongsToMany
    {
        $categories = $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
        return $categories;
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the current user has prime Role of Portal Manager.
     */
    public function isPortalManager(): Boolean
    {
        return $this->roles->contains('label', 'is-portal-manager');
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the current user has prime Role of Manager.
     */
    public function isManager(): Boolean
    {
        return $this->roles->contains('label', 'is-manager');
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the current user has prime Role of Editor.
     */
    public function isEditor()
    {
        return $this->roles->contains('label', 'is-editor');
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the current user has prime Role of Writer.
     */
    public function isWriter()
    {
        return $this->roles->contains('label', 'is-writer');
    }

    public function roles(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether current User has the given role.
     * Given role can be a Role object or string or int
     *
     * @param Role|string|int $role
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function hasRole($role)
    {
        //dd('a');
        /** When $role is an object of class Role */
        if ($role instanceof Role) {
            return !!$role->intersect($this->roles)->count();
        }
        /** When $role is an integer */
        if (is_int(($role))) {
            return $this->roles->contains('id', $role);
        }
        /**
         * When $role is string
         *  - Check against id (in case id is uuid stored as string)
         *  - Check against name
         *  - Check against label
         */
        if (is_string($role)) {
            return !!(
                $this->roles->contains('id', $role) ||
                $this->roles->contains('name', $role) ||
                $this->roles->contains('label', $role)
            );
        }
    }

    public function hasRoleByName($role)
    {
        if ($role == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (is_string($role)) {
            return $this->roles->contains('name', $role) || $this->roles->contains('label', $role);
        } else {
            return !!$role->intersect($this->roles)->count();
        }
    }
}
```

we want to get all categories (one or many) for each user like with this code:

```php
$user = User::find(1);
return $user->categoires();
```

Comment: did you try remove the () from categories as i know adding () will return querybuilder, try to return $user->categories which should return an array. Please give more details if there is any errors and sorry if i didn't get your point correctly

Comment: @Znar `$user->categoires();` is only sample code

Comment: if you only want to get user categories then this should be retrieved by $user->categories, sorry still i don't what you are looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following trait

```
namespace App\Concerns;

use App\Models\Category;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;

trait HasCategories
{
    /**
     * Get all Categories associated with the User in nested tree structure
     */
    public function availableCategories(): Collection
    {
        $categories = $this->categories;

        $parents = $categories->filter(fn($cat)  =>
           !in_array($cat->parent_id, $categories->pluck('id')->all()) || is_null($cat->parent_id)
        );

        $parents->map(fn($parent) => $this->setNested($parent, $categories));

        return $parents;
    }

    /**
     * Set the nested structure for the given $parent with relation.
     */
    protected function setNested($parent, $categories)
    {
        $parent->setRelation('subcategories', $categories->where('parent_id', $parent->id));
        $parent->subcategories->map(function($sub) use($categories){
            if($categories->contains('parent_id', $sub->id)) {
                $this->setNested($sub, $categories);
            }
            return $sub;
        });

        return $parent;
    }
}
```